# How to disable SEO for my website?

Tags: seo

People struggle to increase the SEO of their websites, I also do the same for my other websites, always studying the SEO training videos, reading blogs for SEO.

But for a website I made for a school I need the reverse, I want this website not to be listed in any of search engines, because the website is intended to be used only the School's staff and students who already have the direct link to the website.

Comment: this question will be more suitable in [Web Master Stack Overflow](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw if its better to be in Web Master Stack Overflow, than how to move it there ? may be someone else have the same issue and can benefit from this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The safest method if you want to hide the website from the public (world) is to password protect it, but if you want to disable the SEO for your website then use the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

You can also use a `robots.txt` file in your site's root containing the following content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

It should be noted that is up to the search engines indexing your site whether to honor the `robots.txt`; they are not obliged to.

Comment: I think you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Put `robots.txt` to your website root folder. Its content should be,

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

If youy are using google webmaster tools, you can see [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en&rd=1) to remove your entire site from google index. For other search engines, you can do this also in their webmaster tools.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in robots.txt in your root path

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

It should appear as http://www.yourdomain.example/robots.txt

Maybe you can use also some kind of basic authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by simply adding the :

```
put a meta tag like: <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

In the `<head>` element of page!

For other way see the @HüseyinBABAL answer

for more [**refere**](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html)